# Multi modal transport network and graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am attempting to model a multi layered transport graph with points that allow for travellers to laterally transfer between graphs, in order to make use of different transport nodes. Conceptually, this can graphically illustrated as:

[image: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877042811014170]

In my model, agent's can make use of different pieces of infrastructure depending on who they are. For example, a car can access the road network but not the rail network. In order to do this I plan to create `graph permission groups`

For each graph permission group there will be the associated permitted agents. This would look like this:

```
Graph Permission Group  Permitted Agents
A   Walking, Car, Bicycle & Bus
B   London Underground
C   TfL Overground & National Rail
D   TfL River Bus
E   London Tramlink
```

In order to do this I must distinguish between different graphs and apply a policy to that graph.

My question is do I apply a policy to the vertices or edges? I had naively thought that applying a policy to all vertices would inherently then apply the policy to the edges. I have been informed this isn't correct and it is clear I don't have a good conceptual understanding of graph theory. How should I best go about distinguishing between different graphs?

Comment: It seems that the mode of travel is implied by the node you are on. You could address this with more finely divided node classes (e.g., London Underground, TfL modes, etc).